# Try / except statement causes sql query not to run properly

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, try-except

I have a python script that pulls sql queries from a database but unfortunately the database has performance issue and sometime kills my script. My script loops through a .txt file to get the domain_name that is used in the sql query. I would like to implement try and except into my script so it will automatically continue retrying even when the connection to the database is lost momentarily. My code and error message is below and I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

**Error message**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2:38pm", line 63, in 
    connect_to_db()
  File "2:38pm", line 55, in connect_to_db
    pprint.pprint(unique_domains)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'unique_domains' referenced before assignment

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
cursor = conn.cursor()

def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        try:
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                print(domain_name)
                domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()


                cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_k$
FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))


                unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))

        except:
            print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")




        pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

        outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
        with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: What should `unique_domains` be if you can't connect to the database?  Why are you suppresing the error that would raise?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh unique_domains should be nothing if I can't connect to the database. I'm not trying to suppress the error I'm raising. How can I fix the error from being suppressed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that on line 55 you call `pprint.pprint(unique_domains)` which is defined in your `try`.  So if the `try` fails, you won't have it to `pprint` outside of it.

What you could do so it won't error out is simply define `unique_domains` before your `try`, you could set it to `''` or `None` just depends on what you want to do with it if it's failed.  That should get you past this speed bump, good luck!  :)

If you'd like to your DB connection to retry, you could loop your `try` `except` logic a defined number of times.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do I want to keep unique_domains = cursor.fetchall() inside the connect_to_db function or outside?

Comment: I think I would just toss `unique_domains = ''` directly below your `with open` and above your `try`  it will at least get you past this bug :)  If you've found my answer helpful I would appreciate it being accepted :)  good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried that and I'm still getting the same error. Where should I put con and cursor?